# Multicolumn cell use all space available

Tags: tables

How can I make the text to use the space available on the last 3 columns of the first row? I can keep increase the value until it is there but should be a dynamic way to get the available width, isn't it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|c|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|C{0.9cm}|} 
\hline 
\textbf{Year/Month} & \textbf{Jan.} & \textbf{Fev.} & \textbf{Mar.} & \textbf{Abril} & \textbf{Maio} & \textbf{Jun.} & \textbf{Jul.} & \textbf{Agos.} & \textbf{Set.} & \textbf{Out.} & \textbf{Nov.} & \textbf{Dez.} \\
\hline 
    \textbf{1º} & 
    \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} test &
    \multicolumn{3}{C{3cm}|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Suspendisse at sodales turpis. Ut ornare vulputate ligula. Sed placerat consectetur ante, et placerat tortor tempor et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code, not just a snippet?

Comment: update with all the code needed

Comment: Your width calculation for the usable width of the combined final three columns is off. Instead of `C{3cm}`, you should write `C{\dimexpr2.7cm+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}`. `2.7cm=3*0.9cm`; `2*2\tabcolsep` comes from the intercolumn whitespace between cols 10&11 and 11&12; and `2\arrayrulewidth` comes from the two unused column dividers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with use of `tabularx` and `ragged2e` packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c| *{12}{C|}}
    \hline
\textbf{Year/Month} & \textbf{Jan.} & \textbf{Fev.} & \textbf{Mar.} & \textbf{Abril} & \textbf{Maio}
                    & \textbf{Jun.} & \textbf{Jul.} & \textbf{Agos.} & \textbf{Set.} & \textbf{Out.}
                    & \textbf{Nov.} & \textbf{Dez.} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\cellcolor{white}{\textbf{1º}}
    &   \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
        &   test    &   \multicolumn{3}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}X|}{Suspendisse at sodales turpis. Ut ornare vulputate ligula. Sed placerat consectetur ante, et placerat tortor tempor et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

if you prefer to have in last `multicolum` centered text, than replace `\RaggedRight` with `\Centering` or with `\centering\arraybackslash`, when you not like hyphenate a text.

Comment: if you add another column and and change one multicolumn to 7 and the other to 4 it doesn't work: \cellcolor{white}{\textbf{1º}}
    &   \multicolumn{7}{c|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
        &   test    &   \multicolumn{4}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}X|}{Suspendies, nascetur ridiculus mus.} \\

Comment: @metRo_, what you mean with "doesn't work"? if you change number of columns in the second `multicolumn` cell, you should adequately change their width: `\multicolumn{4}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth}X|}{...}`

Comment: thank you, I though it was dynamically calculated

Comment: how can I center the text? https://imgur.com/a/2wRQOmO

Comment: @metRo_, i mentioned this in my answer: instead of `\RaggedRight` use `\centering\arraybacslash` (if you refer to the last column)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how wide are the columns to span, you can compute the width to assign to the multicolumn, precisely

> the width times the number of the columns, plus two `\tabcolsep` spaces for each column except one (provided by `\multicolumn` itself) plus `\arrayrulewidth` for each column except one.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0.5in}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\multiC}[2]{% #1 = number of cells to span, #2 = width of C cols
  \multicolumn{#1}{C{\dimexpr#2*#1+2\tabcolsep*(#1-1)+\arrayrulewidth*(#1-1)}|}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\newcommand{\mname}[1]{\makebox[0.9cm]{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{tabular}{ |c| *{12}{C{0.9cm}|} }
\hline 
\textbf{Year/Month} &
  \mname{Jan.} & \mname{Fev.} & \mname{Mar.} & \mname{Abril} &
  \mname{Maio} & \mname{Jun.} & \mname{Jul.} & \mname{Agos.} &
  \mname{Set.} & \mname{Out.} & \mname{Nov.} & \mname{Dez.} \\
\hline 
\textbf{1º} & 
  \multiC{8}{0.9cm}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.} & 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} test &
  \multiC{3}{0.9cm}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Suspendisse at sodales turpis.
    Ut ornare vulputate ligula. Sed placerat consectetur ante, et placerat
    tortor tempor et. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
    montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]